# Django Unhasable Type List even though im passing in an object ?(many to many field)

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-database

I am trying to run a migration script for my django app, but I keep getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` even though I am clearly passing in an Object:

I get:

```
 error line 87, in buildCisc
    c.exclusions.add(exclus)
line 944, in add
    self._add_items(
line 1119, in _add_items
    target_ids = self._get_target_ids(target_field_name, objs)
line 1059, in _get_target_ids
    target_ids.add(target_id)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

when I run the following code

```
...

        for ex in exclusionList:
            if len(Course.objects.filter(ID=ex)) > 0:  # exclusion course already exsists
                exclus = Course.objects.filter(ID=ex)
                c.exclusions.add(exclus[0])
            else:  # exclusion course does not exsist yet so we must create it first
                exclus = Course(ID=ex)
                exclus.save()
                c.exclusions.add(exclus) #this is line 87 causing the error
```

where `c` is a Course object create in prior code, `exclusions` is a many to many field from Course to itself, 'ex' is just a string.
if I try using `exclus = Course.objects.create(ID=ex)` instead that also gives the same error. The error seems to be saying that the exclus that I am passing in to `c.exclusions.add` is a list, but it is very clearly an object. I even tried switching exclus to exclus[0] to see if it somehow thought it was a list, but this gave me `error: Course Object not iterable` so it is saying it is of type Object, so I am very confused with error message. any ideas?

edit: I believe to have solved the issue, the `exclus = Course(ID=ex)` was the problem, specifically `ex`. For some reason in my read in phase, it got set to a list somehow and not a string like I thought it was

Answer (score 0):

Since `c` is a Course object, it contains a list and that's the part that cannot be hashed. Try using `.append()` instead of `.add()`. The `add()` method is for sets and those require that the object be hashed since it needs to compare items for uniqueness.

Comment: unfortunately, using that gave me a new error:

`AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Can you post your Course model so we can see how it's defined?